# Django: Is it OK to set a field to allow null which is assigned in clean func?

Tags: python, django, database

My Career model has fields, `since`, `until`, and `currently_employed`.

```
# resume/models.py
...
class Career(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    since = models.DateField()
    until = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    currently_employed = models.BooleanField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    achivement = models.TextField(default='')
```

I'd like to set `until` to current date if `currently_employed` is checked in the django(python) code, not in the template(html/js), as possible.

```
# resume/forms.py
...
class CareerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data['currently_employed'] == True:
            cleaned_data['until'] = timezone.now().date()
        # Check since < until
        if cleaned_data['since'] >= cleaned_data['until']:
            raise ValidationError('"Until" should be later than "Since"')
    ...
```

Is it OK to set the `until` nullable?(and its form field set `required=False`)

However, it would not be null in my logic since by currently employed, or user put that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the 'until' field as null in the database. If you set it to the current date then it's incorrect the following day as long as the user is still employed. You can still have a convenience which returns the current date if the user is still employed. This also means that the `currently_employed` database field becomes redundant.

```
class Career(models.Model):
    ...
    _until = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def until(self):
        return self._until or timezone.now().date()

    @property
    def currently_employed(self):
        return self._until is None
```

Comment: Wow, using null reduce a column!

Comment: but in this way I can't set the `currently_employed`\`s widget and render it in template right?